# External 0~10v controlled by a MCU

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, stm32, dac

Newbie question :
I have an external power supply which gives me 10volts reference. 
The machine I need to command is reading an analog order from 0V (minimum speed) to 10V (maximum speed) and I use a STM32WB55.

My solution is to add a DAC and then an op-amp.

Do you see another solution?

Thank you

Comment: What resolution is required in mV? Sensitivity of 100mV step into 10V is only 7bits of resolution and can be hacked, but say 10mV steps a DAC is most sane. A DAC also allows you to easily  calibrate common mode issues like ground loop current or voltage drop at the sampling side  by using a span slightly more than 10V and calibration codes. Please provide more info on the analog protocol requirements.

Comment: https://www.edn.com/design/integrated-circuit-design/4312523/Create-a-DAC-from-a-microcontroller-s-ADC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) PWM output and low-pass filter
2) digital potentiometer.

Comment: Apparently I don't have pwm on stm32wb55. Digital potentiometer could be OK if with i2c control

Comment: @vib Of course it has PWM, I challenge you to find any microcontroller from the last 20 years without a timer with hardware PWM. Page 46 of the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32wb55rg.pdf) lists 6 timers, with 14 capture/compare channels in total.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a few DACs that will directly output 0-10V with 3V SPI or similar serial control, but they are mostly designed for process control and other high performance applications,  I doubt the cost differential is worth it if you have a low end application (and even for higher end applications the cost hit is significant). Eg. LTC1257, DAC8771 etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options from Alex.  Another two are:-

1. [Bit bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging) (emulate) a PWM type function.  The STM32WB55 runs at   64MHz. That should provide enough clout to do PWM in software.  Then low pass filter, but be aware that getting a nice clean DC voltage may require experimentation.  Especially if the output levels are to change quickly. There's some calculation details [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/low-pass-filter-a-pwm-signal-into-an-analog-voltage/).
2. You can create a DIY DAC with a bunch of resistors in a configuration called a [resistor ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor_ladder).  Then buffer and amplify with the op amp, or other voltage amplifier (may need to cater for an offset though).  [This](https://www.instructables.com/id/R2R-Digital-Analog-Converter-DAC/) is an example of someone's efforts, but it will depend on the bit depth you're after and how many I/O pins you have free.

Remember that all of your design will be a little *soft* if there's no revs feedback from the motor shaft. This may affect how much output resolution you want to build in.